# Laravel: Unable to execute Python script with Process

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to execute Python3 script from Laravel but it throws following error:

```
The command "python3 /path/to/file.py gen_address" failed. Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins) Working directory: /public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ python3: can't open file '/path/to/file.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

`sudo` is not allwoed from `Process` hence can't use either.

Answer (score 0):

Change file permissions to `644`, yes you can't use `sudo` but you can give file permissions to that py file from terminal so php can use it.

Command: `chmod 644 file.py` (chmod have multiple options, if you need them, use it).

Comment: I changed it yet I am having issue.